# Highcharts plot weekly data (JS)

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to plot the following object but it gives me a chart with the following x axis : Thursday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Saturday, Sunday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday

```
var myData = [
    {date: "2018-08-02 00:00:00", value : "626.12"},
    {date: "2018-08-02 00:50:00", value : "626.95"},
    {date: "2018-08-03 00:40:00", value : "646.23"},
    {date: "2018-08-04 00:60:00", value : "656.5O"},
    {date: "2018-08-04 00:50:00", value : "656.65"},
    {date: "2018-08-05 00:30:00", value : "666.32"},
    {date: "2018-08-05 00:30:00", value : "666.63"},
    {date: "2018-08-06 00:30:00", value : "686.92"},
    {date: "2018-08-07 00:30:00", value : "696.21"},
    {date: "2018-08-07 00:40:00", value : "696.54"}
];
```

I tried to filter my object with ES6 array method filter() but I didn't manage to make something like :

```
var weekly = [
    {date: "2018-08-02 00:00:00", value : "626.12"},
    {date: "2018-08-03 00:40:00", value : "646.23"},
    {date: "2018-08-04 00:60:00", value : "656.50"},
    {date: "2018-08-05 00:30:00", value : "666.32"},
    {date: "2018-08-06 00:30:00", value : "686.92"},
    {date: "2018-08-07 00:30:00", value : "696.21"}
];
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to filter the array?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myData = [
    {date: "2018-08-02 00:00:00", value : "626.12"},
    {date: "2018-08-02 00:50:00", value : "626.95"},
    {date: "2018-08-03 00:40:00", value : "646.23"},
    {date: "2018-08-04 00:60:00", value : "656.5O"},
    {date: "2018-08-04 00:50:00", value : "656.65"},
    {date: "2018-08-05 00:30:00", value : "666.32"},
    {date: "2018-08-05 00:30:00", value : "666.63"},
    {date: "2018-08-06 00:30:00", value : "686.92"},
    {date: "2018-08-07 00:30:00", value : "696.21"},
    {date: "2018-08-07 00:40:00", value : "696.54"}
];

myData = myData.reverse().filter((obj, index) => {
  if(index !== myData.length-1) {
    return obj.date.split(' ')[0] !== myData[index+1].date.split(' ')[0]
  }
  return true;
}).reverse();

console.log(myData)
```